# Camera Android : Saving images

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-camera

I am capturing image in android. In the picture callback function I have saved the image 
here is my saving code

```
String number = Integer.toString(image_number);
                    Log.e("pathhhhhhhhhhhhhhh", "/sdcard/img-"+number+".jpg");
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/img-"+number+".jpg");
                    Log.e("image number", Integer.toString(image_number));
                    image_number++;

                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e){
                    Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
                }
```

Its working fine for 2.2 emulator but when I run in emulator 3.0 its shows error

here is the error

```
01-06 04:55:47.398: ERROR/pathhhhhhhhhhhhhhh(424): /sdcard/img-0.jpg
01-06 04:55:47.398: DEBUG/CAMERA(424): /sdcard/img-0.jpg (Permission denied)
```

help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code before calling camera activity,

```
     Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/picturename.png"));
     camera.putExtra("output", uriSavedImage);
     startActivityForResult(camera, 1);
```

Comment: I used camera as a service